# Getting a 404 on angular.js on a MEAN app using gulp

Tags: angularjs, express, gulp, bower, mean-stack

I am attempting to setup a new MEAN app using gulp and bower but I keep getting 404 errors on my bower dependencies when I start my app. I used express-generator to get my folder structure, but I wanted to use gulp to inject my frontend dependencies from bower and my javascript files into my index file.

Folder structure:

```
.
+-- bin
|   +-- www
+-- lib (bower_components)
|   +-- angular
|   +-- angular-ui-router
+-- node_modules
|   +-- ...
+-- public
|   +-- javascripts
|   |   +-- angularApp.js
+-- routes
|   +-- index.js
|   +-- users.js
+-- views
|   +-- index.ejs
+-- app.js
+-- gulpfile.js
+-- bower.json
+-- package.json
```

And my gulpfile:

```
'use strict';

var gulp = require('gulp'),
    browserSync = require('browser-sync'),
    inject = require('gulp-inject'),
    nodemon = require('gulp-nodemon'),
    wiredep = require('wiredep').stream,
    reload = browserSync.reload;

var paths = {
    scripts: ['public/javascripts/**/*.js']
};

var nodemonOptions = {
    script: 'bin/www',
    ext: 'js',
    env: { 'NODE_ENV': 'development' },
    verbose: false,
    ignore: [],
    watch: ['bin/*', 'routes/*', 'app.js']
};

gulp.task('inject', function(){
    return gulp.src('./views/index.ejs')
        .pipe(inject(gulp.src(paths.scripts, {read:false})))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./views'));
});

gulp.task('wiredep', function(){
    gulp.src('./views/index.ejs')
        .pipe(wiredep({
            directory: './lib',
            bowerJson: require('./bower.json')
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./views/'));
});

gulp.task('start', function(){
    nodemon({
        script: 'bin/www',
        ext: 'js',
        env: { 'NODE_ENV': 'development' },
        verbose: false,
        ignore: [],
        watch: ['bin/*', 'routes/*', 'app.js']
    })
        .on('restart');
});

gulp.task('default', ['inject', 'wiredep', 'start'], function(){
    gulp.watch(paths.scripts, ['inject', reload]);
});
```

I know my gulpfile is injecting angular, angular-ui-router, and angularApp.js into my index.ejs file, they show up as:

```
<script src="../lib/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="../lib/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
<script src="/public/javascripts/angularApp.js"></script>
```

but when I start the app, nothing shows up on localhost:3000 and instead there are 3 errors in the console giving me GET 404 errors on localhost:3000/lib/angular/angular.js and so on for the other 2 files.

Apologies if this isn't formatted correctly or if I haven't provided enough information, let me know if I need to provide more code/info.

Comment: what do your www and app.js look like?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used express-generator, but in your `app.js` server code, are you telling Express to serve the files located in your lib?  Try something like:

```
app.use('/lib', express.static(process.cwd() + '/lib'));
```